# Object definition in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I currently have the following, in a TypeScript app:

```
interface Data {
    url: string,
    // more stuff
}

(...)

export class something() {
    public data: Data;
}

method(){
    this.data.url = "things";
}
```

The issue is that every time i try to give data.url a value, I get an error saying I cannot set the property url of undefined.
What am I doing wrong? And why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to initialize the data field with an object : `export class something {
    public data: Data = { url: "" };
}`

Answer (score 0):

1) The class declaration syntax is wrong, it should be

```
export class something { 
}
```

and NOT

```
export class something() { 
}
```

2)  `method` is defined outside of the class, it should be inside the class

3)  `this.data` is not instantiated, it's `undefined`, and you're trying to access `url` property of an `undefined` variable, hence the error.

```
interface Data {
    url: string,
    // more stuff
}

(...)

export class something {
    public data: Data;
    method(){
        this.data = {
           url: "things",
           // more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to access `method` from outside of the class, then you need to instantiate the class `something`.

```
method() {
    let obj = new something();
    obj.data = {
        url: "things",
        // more stuff
    }
}
```